# Selecting more than one feature using values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, features, select-by-attribute

What should I do if I want to select more than one feature using values?

For selecting a single feature, I enter an expression like this which works:

```
"LINK" = 28
```

Assume `"LINK"` as a field in the above example. Now what if I want to select more fields like that. I expect something like this:

```
"LINK" = [28, 56]
```

The above expression doesn't work (obviously). Is there a way to achieve this in QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:
Use the `IN` (*include*) instead of `=` (*equal*)

`LINK IN ('28','56')`

Check https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#operators for more details

Comment: @BradNesom, many thanks for the edit. I should have included that.